# Removing multiple occurrences from a 1D Array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have written a function that will remove multiple occurrences of a letter from a 1D Array. But if there are two of the same letters one after each other the while loop while miss the second letter as index is increased to the next position of the array.

```
void removeAllOccurrences(char text[], char letter)
{
    int index(0);
    while (text[index] != EOT)
    {
        if ((text[index] == letter) || (text[index] == toupper(letter)))
        {
            text[index] = text[index + 1];          
        }
        ++index;
    }
}
```

If the array stores the word [a][b][c][c][EOT], and I want to remove the letter c.
The output will be abcEOT but I want all the occurrences of c to be removed. So the output should be abEOT.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two index.
The first to iterate over your array and the second to point to the position where to store the char.

You only increment the second index if the current char should not be removed.

```
void removeAllOccurrences(char text[], char letter)
{
    int index(0);
    int indexOut(0);
    while (text[index] != EOT)
    {
        if ((text[index] != letter) && (text[index] != toupper(letter)))
        {
            text[indexOut] = text[index];
            ++indexOut;
        }
        ++index;
    }
    // we want to keep EOT ?
    text[indexOut] = EOT;
}
```

Comment: Note: this algorithm is actually *cleaner* using pointers. Upticked regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem from other occurences like when trying to remove an object from a collection:

I'd go backwards! :-)

==>Start at text.GetUpperBound(0) and decrease the index by 1 until you are at 0.

Comment: Another option is of course to use a second array.
You copy each element that is *not* to be removed into the second array and return *that* instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `std::remove_if`:

```
void removeAllOccurrences(char text[], char letter)
{
    auto it = std::remove_if(text, text + strlen(text), [letter](char c)
        { return toupper(c) == toupper(letter) ;});
    *it = '\0';
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/pqDv89)